# How to change order of RecyclerView from right to left?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using `Recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager` . data is shown like this :

```
1      2      3
4      5      6
.
.
.
```

But I want this :

```
3      2       1
6      5       4
.
.
.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You don't need to do anything on the side of the `Recyclerview` to make that happen. Just sort your data before loading it in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: the question is something else.she just wants  a rtl row in grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override the isLayoutRTL method of GridLayoutManager Object,like this:

```
GridLayoutManager gl= new GridLayoutManager(context , 4)
       {
           @Override
           protected boolean isLayoutRTL() {
               return true;
           }
       };
```